# Does the location of package-installed udev rules differ across Linux distributions?

Tags: debian, udev, fhs

Alongside an RPM package, I have been preparing a DEB package for some software which requires the installation of some udev rules.

My RPM package installs the rules in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d`. My understanding is that `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d` is where the rules of third-party (non-distro) packages are supposed to reside.

I've tested the RPM package on Fedora 35 - all good. The rules are applied when the relevant udev events are triggered.

My DEB package currently installs the same rules in the same place, but when testing the DEB package on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, the installed rules are not being applied (when I trigger the relevant udev events). I was able to get it working by moving the rules to `/etc/udev/rules.d`. This makes me suspect that rules in `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d` are not loaded, on Debian-based systems.

After a little research, all of the documentation I've found (RE udev rules on Debian) claims that Debian expects the rule files to be placed in `/lib/udev/rules.d`:

> The rules files (which amount to more configuration for udevd) are
> taken from /run/udev/rules.d, /etc/udev/rules.d or /lib/udev/rules.d.
> Packages install rules in /lib/udev/rules.d), while the /etc and /run
> locations provide a facility for the administrator to override the
> behavior of a package-provided rule.

[Source](https://wiki.debian.org/udev)

I was under the impression that the `/lib` directory was for packages that are considered to be essential to the system. From the FHS:

> The /lib directory contains those shared library images needed to boot
> the system and run the commands in the root filesystem, ie. by
> binaries in /bin and /sbin.

[Source](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s09.html)

Where am I to put these udev rules? My package is certainly not considered to be essential to the system. If I put them in `/lib`, isn't that going against the FHS? And finally, should the location really differ across distros? Why can't I just put them in one place, across all Linux distros?

**Edit:**

I've just realised that, since Ubuntu 20.04, `/lib` is symlinked to `/usr/lib`, so the location of the udev rules will probably be less of a problem on those systems, but I'd still like to know where I should put them, on Ubuntu 18.04 systems.

Comment: `/etc/udev/rules.d` is the right location from what I've seen.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov I used to install them in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, but recently learned that it's only for overrides - packages shouldn't install udev rules in there. It's for admins to manually override default rules. At least that's how I understand it.

Comment: This is not what `man udev` says: *The udev rules are read from the files located in the system rules directories /usr/lib/udev/rules.d and /usr/local/lib/udev/rules.d, the volatile runtime directory /run/udev/rules.d and **the local administration directory /etc/udev/rules.d**.*

Comment: The `/usr` directory (except /usr/local) has always been for distro files only.

Comment: @Artem I tend to consider the rule to be that `/usr` (except `/usr/local`, as you say) is for files *managed by the distro’s package manager* only (because that’s what really matters) — administrators using their own packages are effectively working on a forked distro anyway, and should follow the distro packaging rules, including packaging files in `/usr`, `/lib` etc. as appropriate. They don’t risk overwriting distro files or having their own files overwritten by the distro if their files are managed by the package manager.

Comment: `/usr` is normally meant for for **distro** files. External/third-party configurations settings should be installed into `/etc`. E.g. VirtualBox does exactly that: `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxdrv.rules`. The person talks about *their own third-party* package, so their configuration settings are *not* to be installed into /usr. I feel like you got it wrong/backwards.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, on Debian-derived systems the canonical location for udev files is `/lib/udev`. However you shouldn’t have to care about that in your package build, at least if you’re building using a source package: [`dh_installudev`](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/debhelper/dh_installudev.1) will install them in the right location.

What you need to do is ensure that your rules file ends up available in `debian/package.udev`, replacing `package` as appropriate. A symlink is fine, [see my `solaar` package for an example](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/solaar/-/blob/a7a5bf3b0acdcc932cdcdf3fd02f203a0b21118f/debian/rules#L25).

The distinction is moot since the `/usr` merge, but the reason udev files are in `/lib` is that many of them are essential to booting the system. There isn’t much point in distinguishing essential and non-essential udev files, so they all go in `/lib/udev`.

Comment: hey, I use solaar! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`/usr` is normally meant for *distro-supplied* files. External/third-party configurations settings should be installed into `/etc`. E.g. VirtualBox does exactly that: `/etc/udev/rules.d/60-vboxdrv.rules`.

You're talking about your own *third-party* package, so your configuration settings are *not* to be installed into `/usr`.

`man udev` says:

> The udev rules are read from the files located in the system rules directories `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d` and `/usr/local/lib/udev/rules.d`, the volatile runtime directory `/run/udev/rules.d` and the **local administration directory** `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

Here's another way to look at it in terms of *specifically* udev:

```
# dnf whatprovides '/etc/udev/rules.d/*'
Last metadata expiration check: 1:27:10 ago on Thu 19 Jan 2023 02:17:46 PM +05.
garmintools-0.10-23.fc37.i686 : Tools for Garmin GPS-devices
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/udev/rules.d/51-garmin.rules

icaro-2.0-11.fc37.noarch : Robotic Educational Project
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/udev/rules.d/icaro.rules

mISDN-2.0.22-9.fc37.i686 : Userspace part of Modular ISDN stack
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/udev/rules.d/mISDN.rules

ntp-refclock-0.5-4.fc37.x86_64 : Drivers for hardware reference clocks
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /etc/udev/rules.d/80-ntp-refclock.rules

... many more packages ...
```

I'm pretty sure Debian/Ubuntu follow this.

Comment: Regarding your last paragraph, no, Debian/Ubuntu don’t follow this; there is only one package shipping files in `/etc/udev/rules.d`, and it’s probably an oversight.

Comment: The number of Fedora's own packages which use `/usr/lib/udev/rules.d` is far far higher than those which use `/etc`, so I'm no longer confident in either location.

Comment: Shipping packaged rules in `/etc` breaks the whole `systemctl edit` workflow for local overrides. If you want to avoid shipping rules in `/usr/lib`, the answer is in your man page quote: `/usr/local/lib/udev/rules.d`.

Comment: `systemctl edit` exists for services and units, not for udev files, AFAIK.

Comment: Sorry, yes, but the same general idea applies to `udev` rules: a system administrator is supposed to be able to define overrides in `/etc` and expect them not to be overwritten by package upgrades.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this has only added to my confusion. The quote from `man udev` is vague. It's not clear as to what is meant by "local administration". Can you provide a source, which **clearly and explicitly** states that third party packages should install udev rules in `/etc`? The packages you've provided as examples are not very convincing. **All** of them install files into `/usr` (`/usr/lib`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/share`, etc).

Comment: And one of them (garmintools), since release version `24.fc38`, [install udev rules in `/usr/lib/udev`](http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/aarch64/g/garmintools-0.10-24.fc38.aarch64.html). So they've changed their approach. And there are plenty of examples of other third-party packages that install in `/usr` (Google Chrome, Bricscad, to name a few).

Comment: If you're saying that non-distro packages are allowed to install into `/usr/lib`, `/usr/bin`, etc but **not** `/usr/lib/udev`, where is the source for this? I can't find anything in the FHS that reflects this. Who came up with this rule? If it was a particular distro, that's important as it may not apply to others. None of this is clear.

Comment: None of this is clear or properly defined. If I were you, I'd file a bug report here https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues and seek clarification. Systemd developers must know.